# Retest-Reliability of index "Working Memory" in Wechsler Adult Intelligence Scale (WAIS-IV)

Tags: measurement, test, reliability

I am desperately researching the retest-reliability of the index "working memory" in the Wechsler Adult Intelligence Scale (WAIS-IV). Unfortunately, I don't have the original manual at hand and the internet sources I found just report ranges for all indexes, i.e. [here](https://www.pubpsych.de/retrieval/PSYNDEXTests.php?id=9006581).
I would be glad, if someone could post the retest-reliability value here and — if existing — an accessible source.